# Chef "include_recipe 'cookbook::recipe'" Include Whole Cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, recipe

I'm pretty new to chef and I was curious if I used the 'include_recipe' keyword and only specified a cookbook, would it include all recipes from that cookbook.

E.G.

```
include_recipe 'myCookbook'
```

Instead of the normal format:

```
include_recipe 'myCookbook::default'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it includes the recipe called `default` only.